# c++ laser detection using frame by frame analysis

Tags: c++, image, opencv3.0, tracking

I am trying to create a program that will open my camera, take a frame, and locate a laser point. I want to analyse each frame and find a red laser dot. Ideally, I would be able to insert a line at the x and y coordinate at the centroid of the laser dot that updates with each new frame. The camera I am using to take pictures of the laser is fairly high quality and takes pictures of size 2048x2048 so going through each pixel takes way too long. I need this software to run fairly quickly. I already have the code to open the camera and acquire frames. 
[laser image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXsI9.jpg)

[image]

What is the best way to write the code to locate the central point of the laser point within each frame?

Thanks,

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <iostream>
   #include "xiApiPlusOcv.hpp" 
   #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

   using namespace cv;
   using namespace std;


   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
    try
   {
    xiAPIplusCameraOcv cam;
    // Retrieving a handle to the camera device
    printf("Opening first camera...\n");
    cam.OpenFirst();
    cam.SetExposureTime(10000); //10000 us = 10 ms
    // Note: The default parameters of each camera might be different in different API versions
    cam.SetImageDataFormat(XI_RGB24);
    printf("Starting acquisition...\n");
    cam.StartAcquisition();
    printf("First pixel value \n");

    #define EXPECTED_IMAGES 200
    for (int images = 0; images < EXPECTED_IMAGES; images++)
    {
        Mat cv_mat_image = cam.GetNextImageOcvMat();
        cvWaitKey(20);
        Mat outImg; 
        cv::resize(cv_mat_image, outImg, cv::Size(), .35, .35);;
        imshow("image", outImg);
    }

    cam.StopAcquisition();
    cam.Close();
    printf("Done\n");
    cvWaitKey(500);
}
catch (xiAPIplus_Exception& exp) {
    printf("Error:\n");
    exp.PrintError();
    cvWaitKey(2000);
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: I'm confused to what your actual question is. Take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as well :)

Comment: If it is about optimization you could save where the last dot was and then search in a radius to this position for the next frame because it may not be too far away from the last position.

Comment: The laser you're looking for has some specific feature to use for detecting it?I mean something like specific shape / color / form... something to characterize it somehow

Comment: Yes, it is just a regular red dot laser.

Comment: Could you please post a frame sample with the laser dot inside?

Comment: see link in post